# How to remove odd bottom padding from gradient inside a button on firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

This one has me stumped. I've got an image and a gradient living inside a button and on Chrome all the padding/margin works as expected, but on Firefox there appears to be extra padding below the gradient and I can't isolate what it might be. It seems to be associated with the gradient as when I use display:inline-block the "padding" is gone, but so is the gradient.

How can I keep the gradient where it needs to be but remove the phantom "padding"?

I'm open to changing the HTML structure, but this must also work in IE9.

Chrome:

[image: as appears on Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: as appears on Firefox]

HTML:

```
<button id="sunny-days" data-filter-value="Sunny Days" class="subjects">
    <img src="../assets/images/filters/subjects/sunny-days.png">
    <div class="inner-gradient"></div>
    <span class="imageFilterLabel">Sunny Days</span>
</button>
```

CSS (SASS):

```
button {
            max-width: 169px;
            height: 212px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 12px;
            border: none;
            img {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                max-width: 169px;
                height: 212px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            .inner-gradient {
                height: 50%;
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                top: -110px;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
            }
            .imageFilterLabel {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                z-index: 100;
                top: -152px;
                width: 100%;
                color: $white; 
                @include font-size(14,14);
                @include font-weight(medium);
            }
        }
```

Comment: works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mtbq0e8e/), using FF

Comment: What version of FF are you using? I've got the issue in 43 and 45.

Comment: using FF45.0.2, and I won't see that black background at bottom anywhere

Comment: No that's not a black background. That's the next image down that I was including for reference (in both images). It's the white space between that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after your comments I figured out your issue:

give a `position:relative` and `z-index:-1` to your `button` plus a few tweaks  and here you go:

```css
button {
  border: none;
  height: 212px;
  margin: 12px;
  max-width: 169px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
img {} /* this can be empty */

.inner-gradient {
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: -108px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.imageFilterLabel {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:400;
}
```

```html
<button id="sunny-days" data-filter-value="Sunny Days" class="subjects">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/169/212">
  <div class="inner-gradient"></div>
  <span class="imageFilterLabel">Sunny Days</span>
</button>

<hr />

<button id="sunny-days" data-filter-value="Sunny Days" class="subjects">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/169/212">
  <div class="inner-gradient"></div>
  <span class="imageFilterLabel">Sunny Days</span>
</button>
```